# How to implement Sliding transitions in titanium alloy while opening new window

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, sliding, titanium-alloy

How can we achieve smooth sliding transitions in titanium alloy while opening new windows like the one we have in the classic version previous window slides to left and new coming comes to front from right.Please guide if someone have worked before

Ali

Answer (score 1):

This has changed in general for iOS7 but for smooth transitions, check the [iOS7 Migration guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/iOS_7_Migration_Guide), shown here below:

> **Navigation Transitions**
>
> On iOS 7, when transitioning between two windows in a navigation stack, the bottom window slides half way off the screen, pauses then the top window appears. This is noticeable if you do not specify a background color for your top window, which makes it transparent. As long as you specify a background color for the top window, the application will appear to transition the same as previous iOS versions.
>
> On iOS 6 and earlier, the bottom window would slide off screen as the top window appears on screen at the same time.

So essentially just set the `backgroundColor` for the top window.

Comment: Thanks Josiah Hester, I have set the backgroundColor as well but windows comes just abruptly means no smooth transition effect is appearing. One thing more, I am not using tab groups just simply opening window like this                                            var win = Alloy.createController('login').getView();
win.open();